# Passing in right information when rendering items from Javascript on the HTML side

Tags: javascript, html, azure-devops

I am trying to create an extension for VSTS using their extension kit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview?view=vsts).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        VSS.init();

        var items = {}

        // Get data service and display

        VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then((dataService) => {
            dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection2').then((docs) => {
                // keep a reference to the element instead of searching for it in each loop.
                const itemsDiv = document.getElementById('items');
                const contents = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                // using template strings here to show you another way of working with strings in es6

                    var name = docs[i].name

                    contents.push(
                        `<div 
                            class="listItem"
                            onClick="console.log(docs[i])"
                            onmouseover="this.style.background='#D5DBDB';" 
                            onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">
                            ${docs[i].name}
                        </div>`
                    )
                }

                // finally update the target element one time with your contents. 
                // The new line character isn't required, can just use '', 
                // but this might be easier to read for you

                itemsDiv.innerHTML = contents.join('');
            });
        });
</script>
```

So what my javascript part does is I try to fetch objects from VSTS`s internal data storage (I named it MyCollection2) and display the objects as a list

**HTML part**

```
    <section>
            <nav>
              <div class="create_button">+ Create KPI</div>
              <div id="items"></div>
            </nav>

            <article>
                <h2>Create KPI</h2>
                <br>
                <form action="" id="form" onsubmit="sConsole(event)">
                    KPI Name<br>
                    <input type="data" id="name">
                    <br><br>
                    Actual Value<br>
                    <input type="data" id="actual">
                    <br><br>
                    Potential Value<br>
                    <input type="data" id="potential">
                    <br><br>
                    Goal %<br>
                    <input type="data" id="goal">
                    <br><br>
                    <button type="submit">Create</button><span>Cancel</span>
                </form> 
            </article>
          </section>
```

So all the objects are rendered in the div with the id `items`.

Everything is fine up to this point.

The problem is the `onClick="console.log(docs[i])` part in my javascript part.

My intention was to console.log the document object whenever each item in the list was clicked.

However, this doesn't print the object as I intended.

It just prints `externalContentHost10` and I don't know what that is.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docs` is defined in your function; the scope of the `onclick` attribute (note: should be all lowercase) is not the same. In general, you should [avoid inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these) as they’re not very flexible or maintainable. You should instead use `addEventListener`, which means ditching `innerHTML` and working with proper element nodes. A few other changes I would make are:

- Flattening the promises (removing the nesting) by returning them
- Using `for...of` for iteration
- Using `const` (and `let`, but in this case `const` is enough) instead of `var` so that your variables have the right scope

This gives us:

```
VSS.init();

const items = {};

// Get data service and display

VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData)
   // the callback on the next line returns a promise, which the JavaScript engine will follow, so you don't need to nest the next `then`
  .then((dataService) => dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection2'))
  .then((docs) => {
    // keep a reference to the element instead of searching for it in each loop.
    const container = document.getElementById('items');

    // this loop will remove any existing children
    while (container.firstChild !== null) {
      container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }

    // `for...of` is a simpler way to iterate over a collection
    for (const doc of docs) {
      // create a `div` element
      const div = document.createElement("div");

      // add a text node to it
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.name));

      // add event listeners to change its background
      div.addEventListener("mouseover", e => { div.style.background = "#D5DBDB"; });
      div.addEventListener("mouseout", e => { div.style.background = "white"; });

      // add a `click` listener
      div.addEventListener("click", e => { console.log(doc); });

      // add the new div to the container
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  });
```

If you wanted to use classes instead to manage the styling—which is the recommended method—then you could implement the event listeners using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
div.addEventListener("mouseover", e => div.classList.add("hover-class"));
div.addEventListener("mouseout", e => div.classList.remove("hover-class"));
```

(`classList` has `toggle` and `replace` methods, but they aren’t supported by IE at all, and Edge only seems to support `toggle`, so whether to use them depends on your minimum supported version.)

But you would probably be better off defining a CSS `:hover` class rather than doing all this, if styling is all you want to change.

Comment: This is great! Works exactly as I intended. Thanks. One question that I have is if I want to use bootstrap or other styling options, do I just have to change the id ? I want to know how flexible it is when changing the style of list item.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer. I hope I’ve understood you correctly.